# Set an id for html helper Html.EditorFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using textbox made with html helper "@Html.EditorFor" and now I have to do some action with javascript on its change event for which I need to set an id for this textbox.

Ex. I have to set a string value in that textbox for which I am using

```
document.getElementById("id").value="Test";
```

So how to give id in html.editorFor()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo, new { id = "MyId" })
```

Comment: So can I use this id i.e. "MyId" like this...$("#MyId").change(function () {....});   ??

Comment: Yes. You would use getElementById("MyId")

Answer (score 1):

Use this to set

```
   @Html.EditorFor(m=> m.name, new{@id="test"});
```

and if you will not set id explicitly. Your model property (if string) will be its id like here name is its id.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change) event:

```
$('#id').change(function() {
    this.id="test"
}).change();
```

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a jQuery object here. `this.id="test"` will suffice.

Comment: Actually, after your code you should trigger change event like : $('#id').change(func(){}).change();

Answer (score 0):

use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor
```

instead of

```
@Html.EditorFor
```

example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeField, new { id = "SomeFieldID" })
```

//javascript or jquery

```
$("#SomeFieldID").change(function(e){ ... });
```